# i am created a program for division salary but i don't know what the happen

Tags: android

i want to make program for division salary , I want from user to put his salary and then I want to divide it on 30 days to calculate his budget ,I do not know why the program isn't working.

this is my main activity

```
package com.example.razoo.mywages;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class SalaryDivision extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_salary_division);
}
void SalaryDivision() {
    EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNextAlarm);
    editText.getText();
    double getSalary=(double);
    double resultSalary=getSalary/30;
    text1.setText=resultSalary.toString();


}


 public void click(View view){
    SalaryDivision();
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setEnabled(false);

}
```

}

Comment: is this code even compiled ?

Comment: Could you put real code, because there is a lot of syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

replace your SalaryDivision method with this

```
void SalaryDivision() {
    EditText editText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNextAlarm);
    if (editText.getText()!= null && !editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        double getSalary = Double.parseDouble(editText.getText().toString());
        double resultSalary = getSalary / 30.0;
        text1.setText(String.valueOf(resultSalary));
    }


}
```

and make sure that you're passing number.

Comment: Thanks for helping you so much, my program worked well